# How to get the "next" item in an OrderedDict?

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I'm using an OrderedDict to random access a list, but now want the `next` item in the list from the one that I have:

```
foo = OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
apple = foo['apple']
```

How do I get the banana using just `foo` and `apple`?

Comment: `OrderedDict` seems to be too simple for this. Maybe a horrible one-liner would work? `foo[(lambda keys: keys[(keys.index('pear') + 1) % len(keys)])(foo.keys())]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are OK with accessing those parts of the OrderedDict implementation that are intentionally kept private:

```
>>> class MyOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
...     def next_key(self, key):
...             next = self._OrderedDict__map[key][1]
...             if next is self._OrderedDict__root:
...                     raise ValueError("{!r} is the last key".format(key))
...             return next[2]
...     def first_key(self):
...             for key in self: return key
...             raise ValueError("OrderedDict() is empty")
... 
>>> od = MyOrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
>>> od.next_key("apple")
'banana'
>>> od.next_key("banana")
'orange'
>>> od.next_key("orange")
'pear'
>>> od.next_key("pear")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in next_key
ValueError: 'pear' is the last key
>>> od.first_key()
'apple'
```

Comment: More than OK, it's the insight I was hoping for.

Comment: In python 3.4 the implementation of `OrderedDict` slightly changed (see [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/01437956ea67/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l85)). The elements on the linked list are now objects of the a dummy class `_Link`. Instead of accessing `self._OrderedDict__map[key][1]`, one should access `self._OrderedDict__map[key].next`.

Comment: In python3.5 things seem to have even more changed. The implementation of OrderedDict is moved to C from python. Check [https://bugs.python.org/issue16991]. This implementation will not allow _map i.e. _OrderedDict__map to be inherited. In case you have to circumvent this and use the python module, can try using 
`py_coll = import_fresh_module('collections', blocked=['_collections'])

OrderedDict = py_coll.OrderedDict`

Comment: Why isn't this implemented in the interface for OrderedDict? It seems like such an obvious use case for an OrderedDict that it's surprising they don't come with simpler ways to navigate than iterating over the entire OrderedDict in our code. Wondering what the reasoning behind this might be.

Answer (score 6):

I shudder to think how slow this will be on a list of size, but the *only* way I've come up with so far...

```
>>> foo.items()[foo.keys().index('apple') + 1]
('banana', 3)
```

Edit:

The example was slightly contrived; my actual collection is keyed by dates.  If I need the entry after `today`; found a solution using dropwhile...

```
>>> foo = OrderedDict([(datetime.date(2000,1,1), 4), (datetime.date(2000,5,23), 3), datetime.date(2000,10,1), 2), (datetime.date(2000,12,31), 1)])
>>> today = datetime.date(2000,1,30)
>>> foo.items()[foo.keys().index((itertools.dropwhile(lambda d: d<today, foo)).next())]
(datetime.date(2000, 5, 23), 3)
```

Quite a mouthful.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.X

dict.items would return an iterable dict view object rather than a list. We need to wrap the call onto a list in order to make the indexing possible:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> 
>>> foo = OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
>>> 
>>> def next_item(odic, key):
...     return list(odic)[list(odic.keys()).index(key) + 1]
... 
>>> next = next_item(foo, 'apple')
>>> print(next, foo[next])
banana 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Reworked from your code, this way I guess would be a little better:

```
import collections as co
import datetime as dt
import itertools as it

foo = co.OrderedDict([
    (dt.date(2000,1,1), 4),
    (dt.date(2000,5,23), 3),
    (dt.date(2000,10,1), 2),
    (dt.date(2000,12,31), 1)
])
today = dt.date(2000,1,30)

fooiter = it.dropwhile(lambda d: d <= today, foo)
print next(fooiter)
print list(fooiter)
```

Basically having iterator at the right place is already enough.

Would be cool to start iteration from any position, but not sure if-how possible. Needs some thought.